# How Does Parameter Type (void *) In Objective-C Translate To UnsafePointer<()> In Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

This is an example of an Objective-C function I needed to translate to Swift

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

After much googling I finally found an answer where I could convert the (void *) to a valid Swift type. This type is apparently expressed as  UnsafePointer<()>.

Do you know why (void*) translates to  UnsafePointer<()> in Swift?

What is the syntax <()> called and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<...>` is a *generic specifier*. It resolves the generic placeholder of the generic type to whose name it is appended.

For example, Array is a generic, where the placeholder is its element type. So `Array<String>` is the type of an array whose generic placeholder is specified as being a String - meaning, an Array whose elements are strings. You may say `[String]`, but `Array<String>` is equally valid.

Similarly, UnsafePointer is a generic, where the placeholder is the type of thing it points to. So `UnsafePointer<Float>` is an unsafe pointer to a Float - which might be the first float in a C array of Floats. (That actually comes up in real-life Swift programming.)

`()` is an *empty tuple type*, also known as `Void`. For example, a function that returns no value returns `()` (or `Void`).

So, putting it all together, `UnsafePointer<()>` (or `UnsafePointer<Void>`) is an unsafe pointer-to-void - which, by golly, is exactly what `void*` is.

Comment: Right on point! If you're ever in the Toronto area, I owe you some serious beer!

Comment: After writing that answer, I _need_ a serious beer!

Comment: UnsafePointer<()> has been replaced by UnsafeRawPointer in swift 3.0